# How can I programmatically simulate typing in a contenteditable HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, contenteditable, keyboard-events

I need to simulate the interaction of a user typing into a `contenteditable` HTML element programmatically.

I cannot use things such as `HTMLElement.onkeypress()` or `HTMLElement.fire()`.

I cannot modify the actual code or content of the element using `element.innerHTML` or `element.textContent`, I need a  way to simulate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) with the `insertText` [command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands), which will also fire [`input` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) automatically:

```js
const editor = document.getElementById('editor');

editor.oninput = (e) => console.log('Input');

setTimeout(() => {
  editor.focus();
  
  document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Inserted text...\n\n');
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#editor {
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-height: 64px;
  padding: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

However, note that's currently obsolete and even before it was inconsistent across different browser (same as `contenteditable`):

> **Obsolete**
>
> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div');

const text = "This is my text";
var i = 0;

function type() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    element.textContent += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    if (i < text.length) {
      type(); 
    }
  }, 500)
}

type();
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

It seems like an user is slowly typing in the div. You can tweak the speed by changing the `500` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to simulate a user's input, you can use scriptable browsers like puppeteer.
It is a nodejs package, it gives you a browser that you can control from your code, and it has exactly the thing you need. You can even control the speed of typing, etc.

Here is a sample code that opens a google page and enters the text "Hello world :D" in the search box

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function main() {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  let page = await browser.pages().then((pages) => pages[0]);
  await page.goto("https://google.com");
  await page.type('input[name="q"]', "Hello world :D", {
    delay: 50
  });
}

main();
```